# Why querySelector does not work on remote wordpress (it is working on localhost)

Tags: javascript, wordpress, addeventlistener, wordpress-plugin-creation

I'm trying to select this element:

```
<span
  id={"de" + this.props.wpObject.invoiceitemid}
  style={{
    color: this.props.wpObject.buttontextcolor,
    display: "flex",
    background: "transparent",
    justifyContent: "center",
    cursor: "pointer",
  }}
></span>;
```

With this selector on an other shortcode:

```
let decButton = document.querySelector(`#de${props.invoiceitemid}`);
decButton.addEventListener("click", removeFromCounter);
```

and after selection I'm trying to add an onClick eventListener, but it returns an error:
[image]

In the HTML I can find the ID manually:

```
<span id="de179020309651635" style="color: white; display: flex; background: transparent; justify-content: center; cursor: pointer;">-</span>
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Did you try to log `\`#de${props.invoiceitemid}\`` and see what it contains? (If so, what does it contain?)